# Can you import a pandas dataframe from a module in the same directory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import, module

eg if I have a module in the same directory called dataframe which has a dataframe called df

Can I do:

```
import dataframe

print(df)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can by :

```
print(dataframe.df)
```